# Creating foreign keys from entites that are located in separate tables

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I've been scratching my head at this for hours.

I have four tables `Book`, `Author`, `Allocation` and `WorkSession`

I need to make a constraint that the combination of the `bid` and `authID` exists in the `Allocation` table from the `WorkSession` table.

I tried to create a foreign key constraint like you would normally do but it won't work because the id's referenced are both foreign keys already and I can't create a new key as an identifier for the allocations table

```
CREATE TABLE Book(
bid NUMBER(4),
title VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
SellingPrice NUMBER(6,2),
PRIMARY KEY (bid),
CONSTRAINT EM_SellingPrice CHECK(SellingPrice >= 0)
);

CREATE TABLE Author(
authID NUMBER(4),
fName VARCHAR2(30),
sName VARCHAR2(30),
PRIMARY KEY(authID),
CONSTRAINT EM_Name UNIQUE (fName,SName)
);

CREATE TABLE Allocation(
bid NUMBER(4),
authID NUMBER(4),
payRate NUMBER(6,2),
CONSTRAINT AL_PayRate CHECK(payRate >= 1 AND payRate < 80),
FOREIGN KEY(bid) REFERENCES Book(bid),
FOREIGN KEY(authID) REFERENCES Author(authID)
);

CREATE TABLE WorkSession(
bid NUMBER(4),
authID NUMBER(4),
WorkYear NUMBER(4),
WorkWeek NUMBER(2),
WorkHours NUMBER(4,2),
CONSTRAINT WY_Range CHECK(WorkYear > 2010 AND WorkYear < 2014),
CONSTRAINT WW_Range CHECK(WorkWeek >= 1 AND WorkWeek <= 52),
CONSTRAINT WH_Range CHECK(WorkHours >= 0.5 AND WorkHours <100),
CONSTRAINT FK_Check FOREIGN KEY(bid, AuthID) REFERENCES Allocation(bid, AuthID),
PRIMARY KEY(workYear, WorkWeek)
);
```

Comment: Hi Alex, what exactly your looking for? Only the foreign keys are your concern or you want to bind the Allocation table with the WorkSession        One more thing you can not create a relationship from foreign key to foreign key

Comment: So I finally figured it out and thought this might help with anyone with the same problem, in the end i assigned the foreign keys in allocation as primary keys for that table which got around the error of not being able to find the primarys keys of that table. hope this helps

Comment: What is the Primary Key of `Allocation`?

Comment: +1 - OP solved his own problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE Allocation(
bid NUMBER(4),
authID NUMBER(4),
payRate NUMBER(6,2),
CONSTRAINT AL_PayRate CHECK(payRate >= 1 AND payRate < 80),
FOREIGN KEY(bid) REFERENCES Book(bid),
FOREIGN KEY(authID) REFERENCES Author(authID)
);
```

A foreign key constraint has to target something unique. You can do that with either a PRIMARY KEY constraint or a UNIQUE constraint on one or more columns. Your table "allocation", above, doesn't have either of those constraints.

*If* {bid, authid} are unique in the table "allocation", then you can declare `PRIMARY KEY (bid, authid)` in that table. A foreign key that `REFERENCES allocation (bid, authid)` should work then.